# Is there a special for the following function

Tags: special-functions

Is there a special function that defines the following series

$$T(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-a^2n^2}e^{-2x \pi n}$$

At first I tried the elliptic theta function.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiTripleProduct.html ... is this helpful ?